# listview - how to find out how much pages exist

Tags: android, listview

How can I find out how much pages a listview has. Or in my case - I use rows that all look the same - how many items are shown per page?

I want to hide the fastscroll (a custom library implementation) if there are less than two pages in my listview...

Answer (score 1):

Android `AdaptedViews` like `ListView` has two methods: `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()`. You could take the difference between this values. It will return you the items count on one page.

Comment: I tried that... does not work with the GlobalLayoutListener of the listview and even in my fragments `onResume` the `getLastVisiblePosition()` function returns -1...

Answer (score 0):

try this
listView.getChildCount();

Comment: that I would use, if I can find out how many items are shown per page... Anyway, the item count is not the problem, I know the adapter anyway. I need the screen dependant information, how many items fit on the screen